# How to restrict text entry on Kendo Angular Date Picker?

Tags: c#, angular, kendo-ui, kendo-datepicker

Kendo's Angular Date Picker, restricts the date selection using [min] and [max] to select date from the UI. However, for text entry (user types in the date instead of selecting from the datepicker) user is restricted to enter months above 12 and dates above 30/31 accordingly. But, I need to restict user to type the year as well. Suppose if user types 1996 and my max year is 1995, the date year should change to 1995.

Answer (score 0):

You can make one function which triggers when date is changed, this function should check if your requirements are satisfied with newly entered date OR it should revert back to last value . The Benefit of this approach is that user still can type the values but still it should be inside your validation range.